# Process keeps creating dump files

Tags: windows, terminal-services, minidumps, delphi

We have a Delphi application running on a terminal server that keeps generating dump files. For the same PID, it keeps creating dump files with an interval of around 1 second until the process is killed manually. Another weird thing is the name of the dump files:

```
±_minidump_default_pid_7916_tid_x6590_2012_6_18_13_48_40.dmp
÷_minidump_default_pid_7916_tid_x6590_2012_6_18_13_48_42.dmp
k_minidump_default_pid_7916_tid_x6590_2012_6_18_13_48_39.dmp
Ô_minidump_default_pid_7916_tid_x6590_2012_6_18_13_48_41.dmp
Ž_minidump_default_pid_7916_tid_x6590_2012_6_18_13_48_40.dmp
```

The dump files aren't telling us much and we would like to have a suggestion where we should start looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appeared to be in a component we used to communicate with Oracle. A new version of this component solved the issue.

It looked like the following scenario occurred:

- An exception occurred;
- The component tries to perform an action with Oracle;
- Oracle triggered a minidump;
- The component retried.

**UPDATE:**

Apparently this issue is caused by a faulty Oracle client. Updating to the latest version of the Oracle client fixed this issue for us.

Comment: Pieter, I'm trying to solve the same problem here. Are you using DevArt components? That's what we use here.

Comment: No; it's an Allround Automations component (Direct Oracle access).

Comment: Thanks Pieter, Can you please give us more information on the Oracle component (name, version) that corrects this error ? Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

When I got these files, it was an unhandled action in a program (trying to do something without testing return or thinking it's not going to work). So in the .Net application I made, a code correction was necessary.

These files are created from the Oracle component because of the application issue.

If you just want to avoid creation of theses files, just modify you sqlnet.ora files with theses new values :

```
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED=OFF
DIAG_SIGHANDLER_ENABLED=FALSE
DIAG_DDE_ENABLED=FALSE
```

With these new lines, no more dump files, and real application crashes with details in event viewer.

I hope it'll help, to know that's not always coming from Oracle Part ;-)

Tip found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449276/what-is-the-reason-for-core-dump-stack-shows-from-oracle-lib